# Why hardhat is not checking events args in tests

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap, decentralized-exchange

I have a deposit function, similar as of DEXs, which mints some LPs on deposit.

```
function deposit() public payable returns (uint256) {
        uint256 ethReserve = address(this).balance - msg.value; 
        uint256 tokenReserve = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        uint256 tokenDeposit;

        tokenDeposit = ((msg.value * tokenReserve) / ethReserve) + 1; 
        uint256 liquidityMinted = (msg.value*totalLiquidity) / ethReserve;
        liquidityProviders[msg.sender] = liquidityProviders[msg.sender]+liquidityMinted;
        totalLiquidity = totalLiquidity + liquidityMinted;

        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), tokenDeposit));
        emit Deposited(msg.sender, liquidityMinted, msg.value, tokenDeposit);
        return tokenDeposit;

}
```

Intitally I am funding the contract with `1000 ether`. But when user makes a deposit the Deposited event is emitted with `liquidityMinted = 0`. Atleast it should be 1 or the hardhat test runner should catch this issue.

```js
it("Should able to Deposit",async()=>{
    await erc20Token.approve(uniswapClone.address,etherToWei(1));
    expect(await uniswapClone.deposit(etherToWei(1),{value:etherToWei(1)})).to.emit("Deposited").withArgs(owner.address,1,etherToWei(1),1);

  })
```

but this test case is getting passed instead it should fail because we need liquidityMinted to be 1.

## **Edit**

After @BigRon suggestion I have made the changes as said and here's my full test case:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const {etherToWei, weiToEther} = require('../utils');

describe('Uniswap Clone Contract', function(){
  let uniswapClone,erc20Token,owner;
  before(async()=>{
    [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();
    // Deploying ERC20 token
    const BallonsToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("Ballons");
    erc20Token = await BallonsToken.deploy();
  
    // Deploying Uniswap Clone Contract
    const UniswapClone = await ethers.getContractFactory("UniswapClone");
    uniswapClone = await UniswapClone.deploy(erc20Token.address);

    // funding uniswap contract
    console.log("owner: ",ethers.utils.formatEther(await owner.getBalance()))
    await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: uniswapClone.address,
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1000")
    })
  })
  it("Should able to Deposit",async()=>{
    await erc20Token.approve(uniswapClone.address,etherToWei(1));
    const tx = await uniswapClone.deposit({value:etherToWei(1)});
    // wait for it to be mined
    tx.wait();
    // check the event emission
    await expect(tx).to.emit("Deposited").withArgs(owner.address,1,etherToWei(1),1);

  })
  it("Should able to Withdraw",async()=>{
    expect(await uniswapClone.withdraw(etherToWei(1))).to.emit("Withdraw");
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` outside of the `expect`.
I also think it's best practice to `wait()` until the transaction is mined [per ethers.js docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse).

```js
it("Should able to Deposit",async()=>{
    await erc20Token.approve(uniswapClone.address,etherToWei(1));
    // define your tx
    const tx = await uniswapClone.deposit(etherToWei(1),{value:etherToWei(1)});
    // wait for it to be mined
    tx.wait();
    // check the event emission
    await expect(tx).to.emit("Deposited").withArgs(owner.address,1,etherToWei(1),1);

  })
```

Also if you're using `chai` then the first argument of `emit` should be the contract instance:

```js
await expect(tx).to.emit(uniswapClone, "Deposited").withArgs(owner.address,1,etherToWei(1),1);
```

Comment: I used your method but now I am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'waitForTransaction')`. I guess this error is due to `tx.wait()`

Comment: did you define tx?
`const tx = await uniswapClone.deposit(etherToWei(1),{value:etherToWei(1)});`

Comment: I have edited the question and added my full test case but still getting the error. I have removed the argument from the `Desposit` function of contract that's why I have also removed it from test case